# how to use php sockets to write string

Tags: php, sockets

So Im trying to get my head wrapped around this....

I open the port

```
 $remip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; //Grab my server address

 $fp = fsockopen($remip, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);//Godaddy hosting only 80 and 443 ports work
  //fsockopen(ip address , port, IDK, IDK, timeout delay)
```

so now the ports open or if not maybe some error checking to be sure

```
if (!$fp) { echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n"; exit; } //Not sure what this echos out but its clear how it stops errors
```

So now that the port is open any ip/client can connect on this port????

Ill assume I can now connect....

So on my client I open a socket to my server ip address port tcp connection.....

The php file includes something like

```
else {$out = "hello, 80\r\n"; //out specifies the string to be written , bytes to write
      fwrite($fp, $out); //$fp is the handle
       fclose($fp)}//close the connection
```

at this point ill assume that my client gets the hello written to it ..

finish up by closing the connection

Im entirely new to this so Im attempting to understand some sample code here...
So how long is this socket open for? If i want to keep this port open do i need to do a cron job to launch this file periodically.

Im 100% sure that I have got something wrong here so please set me straight.

Comment: maybe you should search for tutorials on creating a *socket server*.

Comment: @chris If i cant understand these lines of code id be jumping the gun dont you think...DO you have any simple suggestions...I want to learn not looking for code to drop in..

Comment: tutorials are focused on the explanation. i feel you need to do a lot of reading on this subject.

Comment: @chris i couldn't agree more! do you have any suggestions?

Comment: yes search for socket server tutorials. if you're comfortable with java, there's more to be found in java than in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception of what fsockopen does. In your example your fsockopen does not actually open port 80 (as in opening a server socket), but it opens a client socket that connects to port 80 on the server  itself. It actually does open a (client) port which gets a (not completely) random number.
After you connected using fsockopen you can send HTTP commands to the webserver such as GET /index.php

Comment: ok so what ip adress would i use in the fsockopen? the clients ip? im still not totally following your comment" it opens a client socket that connects to port 80 on the server itself....So im opening the port for the client to connect.... It actually does open a (client) port..so i would use the clients ip ?

Comment: when you get a moment id love to hear your reply

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The IP you use in your fsockopen call is the IP of the server endpoint. So if you want to connect to www.gooogle.com on port 80, you use www.google.com as the first argument and 80 for the second argument (port). fsockopen will then establish a connection with www.google.com on port 80. So port 80 is on the server side (www.google.com in this case) and on your client side, being the server on which you run your PHP script, a client socket with a random port will be opened. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes your responce cause me to go learn a whole lot about sockets and it ended very sad for me...for i cant use it in the way i needed..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `socket_listen()` and `socket_bind()`. There are a few places in the docs that show you how to get PHP listening on a socket: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php

I suggest you read and try them out by simply testing then with a unix tool called `netcat` (`nc <ip_address> <port>` command normally)